# How can I hide all files in vscode that are hidden by gitignore?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VSCode's `files.exclude` setting can hide files from search results and the explorer sidebar, but it doesn't seem to support exceptions/includes. My gitignore file(s) have more complex layered rules, with ignore patterns partially overriden by more specific negated ignore patterns, etc. Is there a way to get VSCode to only pay attention to files that git pays attention to?